# Add a class to body depending on the client's language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the body class of a webpage depending on the client's browser language:

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
if (lang == "en") {
    $("body").addClass("en");
}
```

This will show certain containers depending on a user browser language.

What is the best place to add this code? Should I add it on `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`? Or maybe right after the opening of the body container? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "best". Either would work, so what criteria determines best for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dom manipulating by adding a class. If you are using jquery's document ready is fine. For vanilla JS. It's best to place it on the event  DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you would want this to execute as SOON as possible. If you are showing/hiding containers based on language, I doubt that a great user experience for your users would be to see a flash of language that is not relevant to them.

However you want to do it is fine, but I would put this JavaScript wherever it will execute fastest (`head` tag, maybe?).

The CSS is applied as soon as HTML is applied to the DOM, therefore your users will not see the irrelevant content. But they may if you are waiting for `onload`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it depends of the events that will handle the language selection, the event for add the class to the body should be always before the event that translate the texts.

You can use this approach too, is easy to maintain because the code has a semantic meaning

```
$(window).bind('setup', function() {
    var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    if (lang == "en") {
        $("body").addClass("en");
    }
});
```

And the in the document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('setup');
    //functionality to manage translations
});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sFGnZTLSRJIBHvh1VY01?p=preview) a working example